# How to get text between two string with getMatch in Watson

Tags: regex, syntax, watson-assistant

I am working on Ibm Watson assistant to get understandable structures.
One of them is retrieving string between two words.

The sentences are like;

```
application song name çalar mısın?
```

also

```
application'x song name çalar mısın?
```

and i want get **"song name"** in this sentences. the song name can be anything.

The regex works fine on this page: regexr.com/4ltp1

```
"PLAY_SONG": "<? input.text.getMatch('(?=(?!application)\\s).+(?=\\s+çal)',0) ?>"
```

When i tried to execute that i am getting error as you can see below.

Error when updating context with context of dialog node id [handler_3_1569393700920]. Dialog Node context is [{"category":"action","PLAY_SONG":""}]. RegEx pattern syntax error: error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?=`

What is the correct way in this situation ?

Comment: So you are using `(?<=(?!application)\\s).+(?=\\s+çal)`, not `(?=(?!application)\\s).+(?=\\s+çal)`.

Comment: Hm, I have come across something different. Try `extract`: `<?input.text.extract('application\S*\s+(.*?)\s+çal', 1)?>`

Comment: Note that `getMatch` can return multiple matches from the text and the second argument stands for the match ID, so `0` is the first match, `1` is the second match, etc. That is why it was not working.

Comment: Let's remove some of the old comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the regex engine that does not support lookbehinds. Acc. to the [*Watson Assistant* docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-strings) the regex engine is RE2 and it supports neither lookbehinds nor lookaheads.

Here, you may solve the problem by removing the positive lookbehind with the nested lookahead and rely on a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) using the [`extract` method](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods#dialog-methods-strings-extract):

> **String.extract(String regexp, Integer groupIndex)**
>   This method returns a string from the input that matches the regular expression group pattern that you specify. It returns an empty string if no match is found

Use

```
"PLAY_SONG": "<? input.text.extract('application\S*\s+(.*?)\s+çal', 1) ?>"
```

Mind the `1` argument that tells `getMatch` to return the part of the match captured with the parenthesized regex part.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9OE74L/3)

**Details**

- `application` - a literal substring
- `\S*` - 0+ chars other than whitespace
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 1: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `çal` - a literal substring.